# Best way to implement a function that accepts multiple types

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

Given that there's no Union in scala,

I have a three functions that accept different parameters, but are otherwise exactly the same. How would I best implement this without repeating myself like I do now?

```
  import scala.sys.process._

  def function1(command:String):String = {
    ...
    command.!! // scala sys process execution
  }

  def function2(command:Seq[String]):String = {
    ...
    command.!! // scala sys process execution
  }

  def function3(command:ProcessBuilder):String = {
    ...
    command.!! // scala sys process execution
  }
```

Comment: you need to provide more information, what will happen in the body of the method?

Comment: How can they be exactly the same if they take different arguments? What do you do to a `String` that you can also do to a `Seq` and a `ProcessBuilder`? Depending on the capabilities you need, the answer may be to find a common superclass (`Iterable` being a frequent candidate) or make some [case classes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/case-classes.html) that inherit from a sealed trait.

Comment: I basically just do a `.!!` and `.toString` on for each of them. All 3 types support use of those functions.

Comment: `!!` is only on `ProcessBuilder`, according to [a quick search of the docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/?search=!!)

Comment: Then I guess scala does an implicit conversion for the two other types? Because it compiles and works fine

Comment: What imports do you have? Because without any imports, I get an error when doing `!!` on a string or sequence of strings.

Comment: you are probably loading some implicit class that you didn't mention in your post that is adding that funcionallity to String and Seq[String]

Comment: You guys are right; I was importing something. The post was just updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an implicit conversion loaded from `import scala.sys.process._` that will convert from `String` and `Seq[String]` to `ProcessBuilder`, that is what is making possible to execute the `!` in those 2 types, you can use that same implicit conversion to call function3 with any of those types

```
import scala.sys.process._
function3(Seq(""))
function3("")
def function3(command:ProcessBuilder):String = {
    ...
    command.!!
  }
```

this code should compile, you dont need `function1` or `function2`. THIS WILL NOT WORK IF `import scala.sys.process._` IS NOT IN THE SCOPE OF THE `function2` CALL.

You can find the implicit definitions in the package object in `scala.sys.process`, if you look at it you will see that is extending `ProcessImplicits` which is defining the implicit conversions

Comment: Was hoping for a solution that could be applied to more general cases, but it does solve my problem so I will accept it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you have `!!` defined on `String`, so I can't help you there. But let's say all you do is use `toString`. Then your method works on any type which supports `toString`, which in Scala is literally everything. So just take `Any`.

```
def function(command: Any): String = {
  // Do something with command.toString
}
```

If you actually do need different cases for different types, you can use [case classes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/case-classes.html) and dispatch based on the different types.

```
sealed trait Foo
case class FooString(value: String)
case class FooSeq(value: Seq[String])
case class FooPB(value: ProcessBuilder)

def function(arg: Foo): String = {
  arg match {
    case FooString(str) => "It's a string!"
    case FooSeq(str) => "It's a sequence!"
    case FooPB(str) => "It's a process builder!"
  }
}
```

Since your trait is `sealed`, you'll get a compiler warning if you forget any cases in the pattern match. Thus, you can safely handle every case and be confident you have done so.

In summary, if you want to support multiple types, see if the functionality you desire is available in a common supertype (in the above example, `Any`). This could be a trait or a parent class. Common candidates for this are `Seq` or `Iterable`. If you need different behavior based on a select few types, define a sealed trait and some case classes that inherit from it, so you can pattern match on all the different possibilities.